# Can we ignore some files or folder in a pull git?

Tags: git, github

Can we ignore a folder in a pull git 
like git pull origin master -f /node_modules ??

Comment: Your node_modules directory should not be commited, to start with. Fix the repo instead of looking for a hacky command.

Comment: Yes I know, i'm working with a very new dev junior so he make this mistake and I don't use very well git. How can i fix it?

Comment: If you don't want to deal with working in a specific branch matching the remote, ask your colleague to delete the directory and add "node_modules" in .gitignore, then commit the deletion.

Comment: Do an interactive rebase, where you edit/amend his commit(s) to remove node modules. Or just make a new commit where you remove them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, that is not how pulls work.  There may be a way to approximate what you mean to do, but (1) as pointed out in comments, this may not be the way to go[1], and (2) to understand what can be done, you need to understand a bit more about how git organizes content.

By way of answering the question (and in case you do decide to follow this approach):

A commit in git is a snapshot of the entire project.  You merge commits - not files - and a `pull` is essentially a `fetch` followed by a merge (by default).

If you want to do something non-standard with how the content is merged, then I'd recommend doing the fetch and the merge separately.  So for example

```
git checkout master
git fetch 
git merge --no-commit origin/master
```

Then remove the unwanted changes.  If it's just that files were incorrectly committed, something like

```
git rm -r node_modules
```

might suffice.  In more complex cases you could check out the versions of files from your local master.

Then commit the merge.  *BUT* this creates an atypical merge, sometimes called an "evil merge".  It is not the natural result of merging its parents, so it can confuse both users and certain git commands (like `rebase`).  It's a technique to use with caution.  A variation that avoids this problem would be

```
git fetch
git checkout origin/master
git checkout -b temp
# undo the unwanted changes
git commit
git checkout master
git merge temp
git branch -d temp
```

This separates the change revert from the merge while still getting to the "correct" end result.

---

[1] The probably-more-correct thing to do is rewrite history so that `node_modules` appears to have never been committed.  The problem is, since clearly these commits have been pushed, the history rewrite would require some coordination with every developer who uses the repo.

The clean-up could be done with `rebase`, or `filter-branch`, or maybe even just `commit --amend` - depending how much work is based on the bad commit.

You can refer to the `git rebase` docs under "recovering from upstream rebase" for an understanding of the problem the rewrite will cause, and the work required to fix it - understanding that if a developer does "the wrong thing" when fixing it, it could undo the rewrite.

Then you weigh that cost and work against the fact that if you don't do a rewrite, that node_modules directory will forever be part of the history, bloating the repo with information that you don't want to carry around in the repo.